# How to set the document language in ODT?

Tags: multilingual, odt

Help needed for developing the `pandoc` tool, namely ODT generation -- https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1667#issuecomment-310770083:

> Does anyone know what needs to be done to set the document language in ODT?

Answer (score 1):

The German Wikipedia entry for OpenDocument has an [example](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument#meta.xml-Datei)<sup>[1]</sup> for explaining the ODT format. In the `meta.xml` file there, you can see the language specified (as German) by

```
        <dc:language>de-DE</dc:language>
```

...hope that helps.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Permanent link:
https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=OpenDocument&oldid=166672125#meta.xml-Datei